# Pandas - Indexing on a MultiIndex containing an interval

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, intervals

I have a pandas dataframe `df1` with a MultiIndex consisting of `user_id` values and a `start_date`, `end_date` IntervalIndex. I would like to select rows from `df1` based on the corresponding values in a second dataframe `df2`.

The dataframes `df1` and `df2` look like this:

```
In [1]: df1
Out [1]:
                                 start_date   end_date status  score
user_id                                                             
A       [2017-03-07, 2017-03-11] 2017-03-07 2017-03-11     S1   1000
        [2017-03-12, 2017-04-03] 2017-03-12 2017-04-03     S2   1000
        [2017-04-04, 2017-05-21] 2017-04-04 2017-05-21     S1   1000
        [2017-05-22, 2222-12-31] 2017-05-22 2222-12-31     S3   1000
B       [2018-12-01, 2018-12-22] 2018-12-01 2018-12-22     S1    900
        [2018-12-23, 2018-12-28] 2018-12-23 2018-12-28     S2    900
        [2018-12-29, 2222-12-31] 2018-12-29 2222-12-31     S1   1500


In [2]: df2
Out [2]:
  user_id   ref_date
0       A 2017-04-24
1       B 2018-12-25
```

I am interested in selecting the `user_id`s from `df1` that are also in `df2` and the `df1` intervals where the corresponding `df2.ref_date`s lies within. In this example I would expect to get the third and the sixth rows.

If I use a single row of `df2` I can find the corresponding row in `df1` by running the following:

```
In [3]: df1.loc[['A']].index.get_level_values(1).get_indexer([pd.to_datetime('2017-04-24')])
Out [3]: array([2])
```

Is there a way to use arrays to do the indexing in one go?

Here the code to create the dataframes:

```
users = {'user_id': ['A','A','A','A', 'B','B','B'],
         'start_date': ['2017-03-07', '2017-03-12', '2017-04-04', '2017-05-22', '2018-12-01', '2018-12-23', '2018-12-29'],
         'end_date': ['2017-03-11', '2017-04-03', '2017-05-21', '2222-12-31', '2018-12-22', '2018-12-28', '2222-12-31'],
         'status': ['S1', 'S2', 'S1', 'S3', 'S1', 'S2', 'S1'],
         'score': [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 900, 900, 1500]
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(users, columns = ['user_id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'status', 'score'])

for col in ['start_date', 'end_date']:
    df1[col] = pd.to_datetime(df1[col])

df1.set_index(['user_id', pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1['start_date'], df1['end_date'], closed='both')], drop=True, inplace=True)



df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': ['A', 'B'], 
                   'ref_date': ['2017-04-24', '2018-12-25']})

df2['ref_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['ref_date'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to merge the two dataframes and then do a query:

```
df1.index.names = ['user_id', 'date_ranges']

df_merged = df1.merge(df2, on='user_id', how='left').\
    query('start_date <= ref_date <= end_date')

df_merged.head()

#   user_id start_date  end_date    status  score   ref_date
# 2 A   2017-04-04  2017-05-21  S1  1000    2017-04-24
# 5 B   2018-12-23  2018-12-28  S2  900 2018-12-25
```

The disadvantage is that the merged dataframe will lose the multindex. However, if you keep `how='left` in the `merge`, the integers indexes of `df_merged` can be used in `df1` with `iloc`:

```
df1.iloc[df_merged.index].head()

#     user_id       start_date  end_date    status  score
# A [2017-04-04, 2017-05-21]    2017-04-04  2017-05-21  S1  1000
# B [2018-12-23, 2018-12-28]    2018-12-23  2018-12-28  S2  900
```

Comment: And, another disadvantage is you creating a cartesian product of rows, hence if you have a large number of rows you might have memory problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Newbie question probably: Any idea how I could assign a value to one of the "selected" rows of `df1` without risking modifying a view (chained assignement)?

Comment: `df_merged` is an independent dataframe, if you change anything there, no updates will be done in `df1`, normally methods return a new dataframe, but always check the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase. If I use `iloc` to select the rows of `df1` and then assign a new value to a column, I get a`SettingWithCopyWarning`:
`df1.iloc[df_merged.index].start_date = '2020-04-24'`
Any workaround?

Comment: Select both row and column in `iloc` for example `df1.iloc[1, df1.columns == 'user_id'] =0` remember `iloc` is integers based, so you cannot select the column by the name, that is why I used a boolean mask, you can also use ranges: `df1.iloc[[0:2], df1.columns == 'user_id'] =0`